# Bypassing using OAuth for GSuite Mails

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail, google-oauth, google-workspace

Is there a way for me to bypass the need to use OAuth for me to send out emails using the G-Suite platform in my application

I am still able to send out using the Microsoft 365 platform but some of my clients will not move to 365 and prefer G-Suite

Comment: Gsuite by that you mean google workspace.   You could use a service account.

Comment: @DaImTo my problem is that I have multiple clients from various organisations that use Google Workspace accounts

Comment: They could each configure a service account for that would grant you access to impersonate a user on their domain and send emails from.   TBH I am never comfortable with giving a third party developer app a service account to my system.  Your only other option is to use oauth2 and have someone on the domain authorize your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a service account. You will need to have the admin of the domain configure [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to an account on the domain.

Once delegation is configured you can then use your code to impersonate a user on the domain and send emails on their behalf.  This is what i normally do with sa a system designed for sending email conversation mails.   When a user creates a new account the system could send an email conformation email. On behalf of say noreply@yourdomain.com

Your issue is going to be with the fact that your clients are the ones who own the domain so your going to have to get the google workspace admin for your client to set this up for you.

The other option would be to use standard oauth2 and authorize a user on the domain and send emails on their behalf.

The issue with that is going to be your application will need to be verified with one of the highest protected scopes. Your app will need to go though a security audit before it is verified.   Last I checked that audit will cost you  $15k-75k

Comment: We actually found out that Workspace accounts are not yet affected by the Less Secure Apps deprecation issue as yet. So we were still able to get some of the clients working for now.

Comment: If you are going though the smtp server you can also have them create an apps password.   You mentioned Oauth so i assumed you were using the gmail api.

Comment: can you add the authorization code you are using?

Comment: The admin needs to configure delegation to the service account there is no way around that.   It must be configured per user.  hence the "Delegation denied for [email]"

Comment: You need to delegate to the user.   Delegation gives the service account permissions to pretend that it is user X if it hasn't been configured for user X then you cant delegate to user X.   Delegation does not give the service account full access to all users.  It needs to be configured per user.   TBH im not sure i would be willing to give a third party application delegation access to my workspace domain.  Im surprised someone was willing to do this for you.